# PS: what does "ps -o comm= -p $PPID" do

Tags: linux, bash, ps, bashrc

I have a script which does `ps -o comm= -p $PPID`.

The explanation says this gets the parent process name.

From the man page I found out `-o` means user defined format, `comm` means command and `-p` means select the process by the given PID - in this case `$PPID`, which means parent PID.

- What does `comm= -p $PPID` mean?
- How does this command work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `-o comm=` means user output should be the command name only, but without any column title. E.g. if you do `-o comm=COMMAND`, it will print you a column title `COMMAND`:

  ```
   $ ps -o comm= -p $PPID
   xterm
   $ ps -o comm=COMMAND -p $PPID
   COMMAND
   xterm
  ```
- `-p $PPID` selects the process by the given parent's `PID`, the `PPID`.

That means `-o comm= -p $PPID` are two independent options.

So your command essentially does give you the name of the parent process by its `PPID`.

E.g. if I start `tmux`, it has the `PID` of 1632. Now I start several `bash` in each pane, which each have the PPID of 1632, but have their own PID.

You can learn more in [What are PID and PPID?](http://delightlylinux.wordpress.com/2012/06/25/what-is-pid-and-ppid/)

I am not sure, but `ps` might look at `/proc/$PPID/comm` to determine the parent's command name.

In my case, executing this command gives you the name of the parent's process, without using `ps`:

```
$ cat /proc/$PPID/comm
tmux
$ cat /proc/1632/comm
tmux
```

Comment: I just meant the formatting is done on top of the output of original ps ?

Comment: Yeah, I guess internally `ps` just has a switch case that prints out given columns, if the `-o` option is given, and a header for each column that has a string following the `=`.