# What is calling my executable *.sh script?

Tags: shell-script, startup

A long time ago I copied/modified a script that used `inotify` to tell me the results of an automatic `clamscan` when something was downloaded to Downloads - I followed this online resource: https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2017/03/05/using-the-clamav-daemon-to-scan-files-placed-in-my-downloads-directory-in-gentoo-linux/.

**My question:** How do I find out what is executing this script, called `clamscanInotify.sh`?

Though the tutorial suggested using `crontab`, which I did and have since edited out of my `crontab -e` file, this script is still somehow being executed.

I have checked;

1. my user's crontab,
2. my root's crontab,
3. all the cron.daily/weekly/etc,
4. `/etc/cron.d/`

and cannot what is executing the script. I've looked in the `journal` using;

```
journalctl -b | grep cron
```

or for when I know the approximate time I downloaded something,

```
journalctl -b | grep -e "10:00"
```

I've also just used grep to search for the string of the name of the executable - `clamscanInotify.sh`,

```
sudo grep -rnw / -e "clamscanInotify.sh",
```

but did not find the string anywhere, not even in `/etc/`.

I do not have `at/atd` daemon and I cannot think of what else to do to look for whatever is calling this executable script, `clamscanInotify.sh`.

It is also not in Linux Mint's `"Startup Applications"` selection using the GUI for the desktop.

I don't simply want to delete the *.sh file, but my screen and terminals filling up with `zenity` windows and messages is annoying.

Any ideas of where to look?

PS

Here is a pic of my `(h)top`;

[image]

Comment: what's PID 8815 at this moment?

Comment: you also have pid 2283 calling it

Comment: It is "bash", the 2nd in hierarchy under "/usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server"

Comment: sbh@sbh ~/ $ sudo ps -p 2283 
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2283 ?        00:00:22 gnome-terminal-
sbh@sbh ~/ $ sudo ps -p 8815
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 8815 pts/2    00:00:00 bash

Comment: So you want to find the "grandparent" of a process? Could that not be achieved with `ps -o ppid= -p $PPID` unless the currently running child (or its immediate parent) were double-forked and thus have PID one as their "foster grandparent"? Also there are alternatives to `crond` such as `atd`. Could it be that you ended up choosing one of those?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slow way would be to use [PS: what does "ps -o comm= -p $PPID" do](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/145775/117549) to capture the parent process(es) until you find something interesting.

Since you're using bash in the script, add:

```
ps -o pid=,comm= -p $PPID
```

and redirect that to a temporary file. Inspect the contents of that file and then inspect the parent tree; if, for example, that file contains:

```
8815 bash
```

then follow up with:

```
ps -o ppid=,comm= -p 8815
```

where here we're asking for process 8815's parent pid and command.

With a Linux system, insert `pstree -s -p $$` to ask for the ancestry chain for the current process (`$$`).

At some point you'll end up with your desktop manager or whatever method you used to log in.

It's entirely possible that one of your bash initialization scripts is setting this up; I would borrow [this answer, for example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277681/117549) and run something like:

```
bash -ix </dev/null 2>trace
```

and then search the `trace` file for the inotify script in question. As the linked answer also says, the best initial guesses are:

- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.profile`
- `~/.bash_login`
- `/etc/profile`
- `~/.bashrc`

... in which case you could try:

```
grep clamscanInotify.sh ~/.bash_profile ~/.profile ~/.bash_login /etc/profile ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: okay thank you. I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685435/trace-of-executed-programs-called-by-a-bash-script but the first 4 I couldn't get to work - my fault I know. I'll start now...

Comment: I had it called in ~/.bashrc (for some reason I don't know).... Thanks for all the help - I really liked learning it!

Comment: Isn't it always the case -- you find it in the last place you look :)

Comment: just a note, i realize grep missed the script name because it overlooked 'dot' files.  adjusting shopt as in:    https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/264523/grep-ignores-files-starting-with-dot/264528#264528

Comment: True; it's not every day that you want to glob in dot-files; `grep` will see them if you list them explicitly (as I did), or if you use a glob that will pick them up, e.g. `grep clamscanInotify.sh .[a-z]*`